# Black Scholes PDE in forward log space

Tags: black-scholes, pde, feynman-kac

In BS world, we have the stock process in log space $dS_t=(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)dt+\sigma dW$. Let's say we want to price $f(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_{t,x}[h(S(T)]$. Using Feynman-kac, we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}-rV=0
\end{equation}

On the other hand, if we consider the forward process (again in log space) $F_t=S_t+r(T-t)$, we have the forward process $dF_t=-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 dt+\sigma dW$ and the price becomes $f(t,y)=\mathbb{E}_{t,y}[h(F(T)]$. Using F-K again, we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}-rV=0
\end{equation}

Somehow I fail to transform the first PDE to the second by change of variable directly from $S_t$ to $F_t$. Since $y=x+r(T-t)$, by chain rule, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, i.e., the first order is the same and so as the second order. So I end up with
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} +(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}-rV=0
\end{equation}
which is obviously wrong and I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably best to use different notation. So first of all
$$
f(t,x) := E_t (h(S_T))
$$
and
$$
g(t, y) := E_t (h(F_T)).
$$
Since $S_T = F_T$, by no arbitrage we must have
$$
g(t,y) = f(t,x) = f(t, y - r(T-t)).
$$

This means that
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + r \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.
$$
As you've already pointed out
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}.
$$
Using this and the PDE satisfied by $f$ you will then obtain the following PDE for $g$:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} -\frac12 \sigma^2 \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2}\right) = rg
$$

Comment: Indeed, it's about notation. Thanks a lot!